# Is there a way to show percentage (0-100%) in an Altair normalized Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to show 0% - 100% instead 0.0 - 1.0 in an Altair Normalized Stacked Bar Chart ?

I tried

`x=alt.X('sum(yield)', stack="normalize", scale=alt.Scale(range=[0, 100]))`

but this does not give the expected result.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)', stack="normalize"),
    y='variety',
    color='site'
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the axis format argument along the axis in question. For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)', stack="normalize", axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    y='variety',
    color='site'
)
```

[image]

Altair uses d3 format codes; more information on these is available [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format).